# Dynamically retrieving data of different types based on user input using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

New to Swift, I am trying to build an iOS app that allows a user to construct dynamic reports. I have created several model classes meant to represent various types of data to report on, e.g. `Widgets` and `Gadgets`, and associated service classes for these models containing the logic needed to retrieve their data. Examples for a model and service here:

```
class Widget: BaseModel, Equatable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let value: Int
    let timeStamp: Date
    
    init(rawData: RawData) {
        self.value = rawData.quantity
        self.timeStamp = rawData.date
        self.id = UUID()
    }
    
    func toString() -> String {
        return "\(self.value) widgets"
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Widget, rhs: Widget) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

class WidgetService: BaseService {
    let queryService: QueryService = QueryService()
    
    func fetchSamplesInDateRange(dates: (startDate: Date, endDate: Date)?) async -> [Widget] {  
        // get samples and return them
    }
}
```

These are based off of two protocols with associated types, `BaseModel` and `BaseService`. What I'm trying to do in this very early proof of concept stage is implement a simple view that will allow a user to select a type of data (corresponding to one of my `Model`s) and run a query for all data for that `Model` within a date range. But I am completely stuck on how to implement the model selection.

I have a basic view file I've been working with that just has one button that executes a fetch function, populating a state variable `results`.

```
    func fetchData() async -> Void {
        let modelService: some BaseService = // not sure what to do here
        let result: [some BaseModel] = await modelService.fetchSamplesInDateRange(dates: nil)
        results = result
    }
```

Because `BaseModel` and `BaseService` have associated types they can't be used in the way above as type constraints, I know, I put them there to give an idea of what I'm trying to do.

I had thought to put the class names as strings, choosable via options in a `Picker`, and then use something like `NSClassFromString` to get the right class for the service, but ultimately this just doesn't seem workable as I have to declare the concrete service class type at some point, this solution just moves around where I run into the `Protocol 'BaseModel' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` error.

Any idea what I'm missing here? This sort of thing using base classes, extensions, generics, just doesn't seem like it should be this difficult as other languages handle it fine (though admittedly with less type safety).

Comment: “Though admittedly with less type safety” that’s basically the catch. By using an associated type, you’re trying to assert a fair amount of type information about return values, whose concrete values won’t be known until runtime. The issue is that to know what type `result` should be, the compiler would need to statically know the type of modelService, but by definition, it’s something that won’t be know until runtime. Once you’re in this spot, static type checking (at compile time) no longer helps, because you’re dealing with things that are determined at runtime.

Comment: You basically have no choice but to return a general type (such as a type erased “AnyModel”), and then conditionally down cast it (a for, of dynamic type checking) when you need to access specific properties or functions that aren’t available via the general super type.